# filtering out nonvalues with php explode()

Tags: php, explode

I have an array with a field of type string in php.

I'm using it to keep track of history. everytime a user performs a specified action the user id is added to the string. I'm using the RedBean ORM, so to declare the field varchar using mysql I have initialized it as:

```
$history_field="0 ,";
```

but when I perform:

```
$history_array=  explode(',', $history_field);
```

I get:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "0 " [1]=> string(0) "" }
```

There should be one element in the array - namely '0' , I would have thought. Is this a bug?
how can  I fix this to get my expected result. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) (and the comments) this is expected behavior, you can use this to filter out the empty values:

```
array_filter(explode(',', $history_field), 'strlen');
```